# Can someone tell me where "Women are not created weaker but more generous than men" is in Bukhari or Muslim?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, uloom-al-hadith, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim

Many people tell me that Bukhari and Muslim "agree" with this quote that Imam Ahmad states but I don't know if that means it is in their sahih or not. Can someone clarify?

> Women are not created weaker but more generous than men. They are created more beautiful and less fierce, as beauty hates to hurt and harm others. That is why they seem weak to people, but in reality they are not. Angels are the strongest of created beings, and women are closer to the angelic nature than men, as they are readier than men to carry angelic light.

This is source that people I talked to have listed: The Fifth Paradise: The Garden of Beauty and Felicity by Imam Ahmad (agreed upon by Bukhari and Muslim and narrated by Abu Huraira (R.A.)).

This is link: http://www.meem.freeuk.com/Miraaj.html

Comment: It seems that all sites I look at which quote the above text don't quote the chain of narrators which is dodgy!

Comment: If it is a quote of Imam Ahmad then al-Bukhari might have quoted it under the title of a chapter.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a link to the source of this statement, as is it doesn't sound like a statement of Imam Ahmad, the source you quoted can't be of Imam Ahmad it might be from a rather doubtful source quoting al-Mi'araj as it seems to me after a certain search! And Imam Ahamd didn't write any book on the topic of al-Israa' and al-Mi'araj.

Comment: This is link: http://www.meem.freeuk.com/Miraaj.html

Answer (score 2):

As Aboudi says it seems dodgy,
I am by no means a scholar but I believe this hadith/qoute is fabricated.

Also couldn't find this in any of the Kittabal-Sittah(Muslim,Bukhari,Abu Dawud, Tirmdhi, Sunan ibn Majah, Nisai)
Some attribute this quote to Prophet Muhammad (Peace and Blessings Be Upon him)
, **as this saying has no actual chain of narrators that can be found( Warning Number One).**

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Whoever believes in Allah and the Last Day
>   should not hurt (trouble) his neighbor. And I advise you to take care
>   of the women, for they are created from a rib and the most crooked
>   portion of the rib is its upper part; if you try to straighten it, it
>   will break, and if you leave it, it will remain crooked, so I urge you
>   to take care of the women."(Sahih Bukhari)

This also conflicts with the quran and hadith as it says to take care of women with delicacy which confirms some weakness.

> Men are in charge of women by [right of] what Allah has given one over
>   the other and what they spend [for maintenance] from their wealth. So
>   righteous women are devoutly obedient, guarding in [the husband's]
>   absence what Allah would have them guard. But those [wives] from whom
>   you fear arrogance - [first] advise them; [then if they persist],
>   forsake them in bed; and [finally], strike them. But if they obey you
>   [once more], seek no means against them. Indeed, Allah is ever Exalted
>   and Grand.(Surah Nisa Ayah 34)

We must separate our emotional opinion and what the Quran/Sunnah strictly mentions. This hadith also implies that woman bare more innate responsibilities then men.

> Angels are the strongest of created beings, and women are closer to
>   the angelic nature than men, as they are readier than men to carry
>   angelic light.

When you say Angels are the strongest created beings and that women are closer to them, your basically flipping the natural roles of men and women around as strength is naturally correlated to responsibility.

The absence of any narrators coupled with numerous strong proofs from the Quran and Sunnah that say otherwise, I'd say this thing is fabricated.

> **BUT ALLAH KNOWS BEST AND MAY ALLAH FORGIVE ME FOR ANY MISTAKES**